# Multiple Authentication Middlewares

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, identityserver3, authorize-attribute

Good Day

I am in the process of moving an API over from using:

```
app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
```

for validating tokens, to using IdentityServer.

I want to however also be able to validate any tokens issued previously, using the above middleware.

So at first I replaced the line above with the following (IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation):

```
    .UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Authority = "http://localhost:5000",
            RequiredScopes = new[] { "api.tablet" },
            ClientId = "TabletAPI",
            ClientSecret = "secret",
        });
```

This worked and correctly authorized requests to protected endpoints, but only for tokens issued by the IdentityServer.
So my setup in IdentityServer is fine I believe, as using a reference token correctly validated and allowed access.

I however want the old OAuth tokens to also be validated, and so doing support the older OAuth tokens as well as any JwT's or reference tokens issued by my IdentityServer.

The way I found to do this (if there is a better way let me know please) was to add both middlewares into the pipeline, as below:

```
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            AuthenticationType = "BearerLegacy",
        })
        .UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Authority = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AuthServer"],
            RequiredScopes = new[] { "api.tablet" },
            AuthenticationType = "BearerIdSrv",
            ClientId = "TabletAPI",
            ClientSecret = "secret",
        });
```

This is were I am stuck, it seems that the IdentityServer middleware is always the one trying to validate a token, and once it fails, it seems it never tries the "legacy" OAuth middleware.

Do I need to explicitly add something to all my [Authorize] endpoints to indicate that both types should be tried? Or is there a way to specify this globally?

[I've found this, which seems more or less exactly like what I want to achieve, but is unfortunately in Asp.Net Core.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore1x#use-multiple-authentication-schemes)

Any help or nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this [link](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation/issues/92), where they suggest to remove the RequiredScopes from the IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions. I tried that and it started working.
So in essence this:

```
app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions()
    {
        AuthenticationType = "BearerLegacy",
    })
    .UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
    {
        Authority = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AuthServer"],
        RequiredScopes = new[] { "api.tablet" },
        AuthenticationType = "BearerIdSrv",
        ClientId = "TabletAPI",
        ClientSecret = "secret",
    });
```

Needs to become this:

```
app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions()
    {
        AuthenticationType = "BearerLegacy",
    })
    .UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
    {
        Authority = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AuthServer"],
        AuthenticationType = "BearerIdSrv",
        ClientId = "TabletAPI",
        ClientSecret = "secret",
    });
```

Comment: I did as you described. The response of requests are correct, but it writes the idx10501 error in the log file.